# return 0 instead of nothing for attribute value that is not available in any collections

Tags: mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I have a document as follow:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5491d65bf315c2726a19ffe0"),
"tweetID" : NumberLong(535063274220687360),
"tweetText" : "19 RT Toronto @SunNewsNetwork: WATCH: When it comes to taxes, regulations, and economic freedom, is Canada more \"American\" than America? http://t.co/D?",
"retweetCount" : 1,
"Added" : ISODate("2014-11-19T04:00:00.000Z"),
"tweetLat" : 0,
"tweetLon" : 0,
"url" : "http://t.co/DH0xj0YBwD ",
"sentiment" : 18
}
```

now I want to get all document like this where Added is between 2014-11-19 and 2014-11-23 but we should note that there might be no data in for example this date : 2014-11-21 and now the problem starts: here when this happens I want 0 for sum of sentiment for this date instead of returning nothing( I know I can check this in java but it is not reasonable), my code is as follow which works fine except for the date that is not available it returns nothing instead of 0:

```
andArray.add(new BasicDBObject("Added", new BasicDBObject("$gte",
            startDate)));
    andArray.add(new BasicDBObject("Added", new BasicDBObject("$lte",
            endDate)));
DBObject where = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("$and",
            andArray));
    stages.add(where);
DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject("_id", "$Added");
    groupFields.put("value",
            new BasicDBObject("$avg", "$sentiment"));
    DBObject groupBy = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);
    stages.add(groupBy);
    DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("_id", 0);
    project.put("value", 1);
    project.put("Date", "$_id");
    stages.add(new BasicDBObject("$project", project));

    DBObject sort = new BasicDBObject("$sort", new BasicDBObject("Date", 1));
    stages.add(sort);
    AggregationOutput output = collectionG.aggregate(stages);
```

Now I want value 0 for the date that is not available in the collections that I have,
For example consider 2014-11-21 in the following :

```
  [ { "value" : 6.0 , "Date" : { "$date" : "2014-11-19T04:00:00.000Z"}} , {    "value" : 20.0 , "Date" : { "$date" : "2014-11-20T04:00:00.000Z"}},{ "value" : 0    , "Date" : { "$date" : "2014-11-21T04:00:00.000Z"}}]
```

instead of :

```
 [ { "value" : 6.0 , "Date" : { "$date" : "2014-11-19T04:00:00.000Z"}} , { "value" : 20.0 , "Date" : { "$date" : "2014-11-20T04:00:00.000Z"}}}]
```

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Why is checking in Java not reasonable? Setting average to 0 for 'nothing' is reasonable?

Depending on the context of your problem, one solution is for you to insert dummy records with 0 sentiment.

Comment: Thank u for your answer ... this is not reasonable because I have for example more than 100 days in one request from the user and then imagine a for loop of 100 or 200 or 300 ... so it takes time which is not acceptable for user

Comment: You sure you cannot pre populate your mongDB with dummy data for, say next 10 years, or even 100? At 100 years, that is "just" 36500+ rows .....

Comment: Yes because the above document is a simpler version of what I really have